# Jmeter test, takes always the same time between start and finish

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

Jmeter is taking always the same time to finish remote test. The jmx script is simple and there is no time configured on it, and there are just one request (only 84ms in local test). 
It happens only on remote test, in local test is ok.

Starting the test on host x.x.x.x @ Thu Aug 14 09:31:43 BRT 2014 (1408019503091)

Finished the test on host x.x.x.x @ Thu Aug 14 09:34:43 BRT 2014 (1408019683082)

Starting the test on host x.x.x.x @ Thu Aug 14 09:35:53 BRT 2014 (1408019753107)

Finished the test on host x.x.x.x @ Thu Aug 14 09:38:53 BRT 2014 (1408019933091)

Starting the test on host x.x.x.x @ Thu Aug 14 09:40:33 BRT 2014 (1408020033110)

Finished the test on host x.x.x.x @ Thu Aug 14 09:43:33 BRT 2014 (1408020213100)

Starting the test on host x.x.x.x @ Thu Aug 14 10:03:23 BRT 2014 (1408021403158)

Finished the test on host x.x.x.x @ Thu Aug 14 10:06:23 BRT 2014 (1408021583154)

Starting the test on host x.x.x.x @ Thu Aug 14 10:07:53 BRT 2014 (1408021673181)

Finished the test on host x.x.x.x @ Thu Aug 14 10:10:53 BRT 2014 (1408021853164)

Starting the test on host x.x.x.x @ Thu Aug 14 10:25:23 BRT 2014 (1408022723204)

Finished the test on host x.x.x.x @ Thu Aug 14 10:28:23 BRT 2014 (1408022903204)

Starting the test on host x.x.x.x @ Thu Aug 14 10:33:13 BRT 2014 (1408023193224)

Finished the test on host x.x.x.x @ Thu Aug 14 10:36:53 BRT 2014 (1408023413225)

Comment: what is your question ? can you show your test plan ? zoom on thread group config ?

Comment: The question is, why always about 3 minutes to finish the remote test?
The same test in local machine have just 84ms.

Comment: Because you have a performance issue on remote test?

Comment: No, if I make a  test script with one request to google.com for example, I have the same problem.